# Triggering a javascript event without a one pixel .gif

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to trigger an event in Javascript to be tracked in Google Analytics when a form is submitted and the 'thank you' message (not a new 'thank you' page) is shown.

I could use onSubmit on the form button, but prefer to track when the 'Thank You' message is displayed.

It has worked using onLoad and a one pixel .gif, tracking the proper events in Google Analytics, using the code below.

```
<img src="onepixelimage.gif" onload="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Petition','Submitted','Test2']);">
```

This works fine. But it seems clunky, uploading and hiding a one pixel image on a page feels so 1997.

I feel like I should be able to trigger this event when a script loads, using onLoad.

But I can't get this code to work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   script.onload(function() {
   _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Petition', 'Submitted', 'Test2');
   });
</script>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
I suspect my Javascript syntax is off, or maybe this just won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the variable `script`?

Comment: How do you know when the thank you message is displayed?

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit a form?

Comment: Apologies for letting this sit so long, thanks for your interest.  I am a javascript newbie, so my answers may be a bit vague.  Not sure what the variable 'script' is - I found this code elsewhere. I am hoping that it references the current code, if that makes sense.
2. THank You message is displayed by the template when particular conditions are met - different HTML is spit out for different conditions.

Comment: I don't know if AJAX is used to submit the form, though assorted jquery libraries are added to the template, but this is not consistent across installations in this technology - libraries and library versions will vary.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have no intention in use any JS framework and your page is already referenced to Google Ad's API try the script bellow in the end of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.body.onload = function() {
       _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Petition', 'Submitted', 'Test2');
   };
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this solution, apologies I have let this question sit for so long.  But here's the problem: the site is using templates, and while I can make a custom template for this page (and page type) I can't add this code just before the </body> tag, which is where I suspect it should be placed.
I need something, just like the <img src onload above, that I can use anywhere in the page: remember this confirmation message is being loaded on an existing page when conditions are met.  Thanks for your help so far.